# Consolidation of stringified numerical comparisons

Tags: python

I have list of comparisons against a variable like this

```
['x < 0.15', 'x > -inf', 'x < 0.20', 'x > -5.5']
```

How can these comparisons be consolidated to result `'(-5.5, 0.15)'`.

I see there's no data structure that supports representation of range of continuous real numbers in python

Comment: Is '(-5.5, 0.15)' a string too? And do you want to perform the list operations on each element of '(-5.5, 0.15)'?

Comment: @MohitMotwani OP wants to solve the set of inequalities which are elements of a list and wants to generate a set that contains starting and ending points of the range of values the element can take. Feels like writing an AI program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) to solve system of inequalities:

```
In [1]: from sympy import oo, solve

In [2]: from sympy.abc import x

In [3]: from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr

In [4]: system = ['x < 0.15', 'x > -inf', 'x < 0.20', 'x > -5.5']

In [5]: solve([parse_expr(x, local_dict={'inf': oo}) for x in system])
Out[5]: (-5.5 < x) & (x < 0.15)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way in pure Python:

```
myList = ['x < 0.15', 'x > -inf', 'x < 0.20', 'x > -5.5']


def andRange(lst):
    gt = []
    lt = []
    for rng in lst:
        if "<" in rng:
            strVal = rng.split("<")[1]
            if strVal.strip() != "inf":
                lt.append(float(strVal))
        if ">" in rng:
            strVal = rng.split(">")[1]
            if strVal.strip() != "-inf":
                gt.append(float(strVal))
    return (min(lt), max(gt))


print(andRange(myList))
```

Comment: Good, but will not work for `['x > -inf', 'x < 0.20']`

Comment: Depends on use case. I interpreted it to be this kind of use case.

Comment: You mean `['x > -inf', 'x < 0.20']` is not a valid use case?